# Biztalk - Non Resumable Suspended Message subscription(zombies)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

In my application, I am getting zombie messages which go into non resumable suspended state because the orchestration is completed during the inflight. I need these messages to retry without losing the data. Is there any way to subscribe to these non resumable suspended state or to read this messages from non resumable state.

Comment: You could use the BizTalk administration console to save out the messages.  However unless your solution has a port where you can re-submit them this might not help.   It sounds like your solution might need to be changed to avoid Zombies.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to Subscribe to Zombie Messages.

You basically have two options which you can use individually in combination to address this situation.

1. Refactor your process to avoid or minimize the possibility of Zombies.
2. Periodically run a script that saves the suspended messages and cleans up Zombie instances.  You can find a sample here: [Saving suspended messages in BizTalk](https://vincentchoo.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/saving-suspended-messages-in-biztalk/)